# Pl/Sql open cursor problems

Tags: database, plsql, oracle10g, cursor

I have code like,

```
create or replace function ... return types.cursortype 
as 
    l_cursor    types.cursorType; 
begin 
    open l_cursor for select ... ; 
    return l_cursor; 
end;
```

this code is used to return hundreds of records daily. 
Will these open cursors cause any memory leak issue ?

Is there any way to close such unclosed cursors in the procedure only ?

Any SQL for keeping track of such open cursor ?

If its duplicate please add references..

Comment: remove the sql-server tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will these open cursors cause any memory leak **issue** ?

**No if you don't leave them opened after using** (for `explicit` cursors), when opening a cursor, oracle creates a [context area](http://www.toadworld.com/platforms/oracle/w/wiki/616.context-area.aspx), PL/SQL controls the context area through a cursor which holds the result returned by a SQL statement. and for `implicit` cursors there is nothing to worry about

> Is there any way to close such unclosed cursors in the procedure only
>   ?

**You can, but don't**, because you opening it for using outside the procedure or function which you really don't know when and where it will be used and how long the using will take, and you have to close the cursor after finishing the use of it. (the cursor will open when you call the procedure or function)

> Any SQL for keeping track of such open cursor ?

**Yes there are**, you can query `v$sesstat`, `v$statname` and `v$session` SYS views:

```
select *
from v$sesstat ss, v$statname sn, v$session s
where ss.statistic# = sn.statistic#  and s.sid=ss.sid
and sn.name = 'opened cursors current';
```

[here](http://www.orafaq.com/node/758) there is a good article on monitoring the cursors.

Comment: Thanks :) one more thing, How to close explicit cursor if i am returning result set to java ?

Comment: You are welcome, if you are opening it in PL/SQL code blocks through Java and if you have used `open cursor_name; ... ;` then use `close cursor_name;`, and if you are calling a function or procedure which returns a ref cursor then don't worry about it they will close when they get out of scope.